# Reportes en Asp Con Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, crystal-reports

Alguien puede ayudarme.
- Estoy creando el diseño de reportes en Crystal Report mismo que se incluirán en la aplicación cliente ASP.
- Todos los datos a cargase en el crystal report los obtengo atravez de un webservice que me retorna un Dataset.
- Estos datos necesito cargarlos al crystal Report para poder visualizarlos en la web.
¿Como puedo hacer este paso de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes los datos en un Dataset, yo haría lo siguiente:
1. Diseñaria el informe a partir de la estructura de este Dataset.
2. En la pagina donde quieres mostrarlo:

```
InformeCrystal cr = new InformeCrystal();
cr.SetDataSource(datos);  //datos es el Dataset donde están los datos
crv.ReportSource=cr       //crv es el visor de cristal reports.
```

Espero te sirva